For the WebPage, the CSS files created are not linked with the HTML files. Despite changes made
I have been developing a website for the past week and I'm using Flask framework. It was executing good until 2 days ago the CSS files linked with the HTML is not displaying properly in the browser.
I tried all the changes, updated them, cleared the browser cache and etc as said by AI tools. But still the same. I'm really confused and blank on how to resolve this issue.
Please help me out.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please provide more information.

Is the file located at the place it's expected to be?
How are you running the server (i.e what command are you using)?
etc...

